# UrlFetchApp works in script editor, not in document

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a Google Apps script for Sheets which makes a request to the Google Books API to look up ISBN by title/author, and the requests reliably work when testing in the script editor, but when I test it with the same data in the spreadsheet itself, it fails with this error:

```
Request failed for https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=Deedy%2C%20Carmen%20Agra%2014%20Cows%20for%20America returned code 403. Truncated server response: { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "unknownLocation",
 "message": "Cannot determine user location for geogra... (use muteHttpExceptions option to examine full response) (line 55).
```

This is the execution transcript for the same function being run in the script editor with the same data, successfully:

```
[16-08-05 14:39:09:772 EDT] Starting execution
[16-08-05 14:39:10:558 EDT] UrlFetchApp.fetch([https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=Deedy%2C%20Carmen%20Agra%2014%20Cows%20for%20America]) [0.778 seconds]
[16-08-05 14:39:10:559 EDT] HTTPResponse.getResponseCode() [0 seconds]
[16-08-05 14:39:10:559 EDT] HTTPResponse.getContentText() [0 seconds]
[16-08-05 14:39:10:569 EDT] Logger.log([found title match for '%s': '%s', [14 Cows for America, 14 Cows for America]]) [0 seconds]
[16-08-05 14:39:10:583 EDT] Logger.log([result: %s, [9781561454907]]) [0 seconds]
[16-08-05 14:39:10:584 EDT] Execution succeeded [0.804 seconds total runtime]
```

I've made the [source code](http://ix.io/1b9g) available if it's relevant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The URL Fetch service uses Google's network infrastructure for
>   efficiency and scaling purposes.

And "Google Books API results are restricted based on your server or client application's IP address" ([doc](https://developers.google.com/books/docs/v1/using#UserLocation)). And for some reason it can't determine the server's location where Google Apps Scripts are running and returns the error `Cannot determine user location for geographically restricted operation`. You can try sending the parameter `country`, just change this line:

```
var isbnEndpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=";
```

to this:

```
var isbnEndpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?country=US&q=";
```

Comment: Surprising that it could detect the location on the dev servers but not on the live spreadsheet, but yes, this works, thanks.